# Calculate the limit:

Tags: analysis, limits, functions, trigonometry

I need to calculate:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{4}}\frac{\sin2x-\cos^{2}2x-1}{\cos^{2}2x+2\cos^{2}x-1}$$

I replaced $2\cos^{2}x-1=\cos2x$ and $\cos^{2}2x=1-\sin^{2}2x$, so this limit equals $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{4}}(tg2x\frac{\sin2x+1}{\cos2x+1}-\frac{2}{\cos2x(\cos2x+1)})$ but we still have $\infty-\infty$. Any ideas?

Comment: You also can start simplifying the expression before going to limits.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Replace $y=2x-{\pi\over 2}$, so $y\to0$ as $x\to{\pi\over 4}$

Answer (score 0):

Since user64494 gave you the answer and the different steps, I shall just tell that the expression you work can be simplified to
(Sin[x] + Sec[x]) (Tan[x]-1) / (Sin[x] + Cos[x])
which does not make any problem.